# Git versioner (by Pascal Welsch) returns git exit value off 128 on MacBook M2, altho it is a git project

Tags: android, git, android-studio

INITIAL DESCRIPTION:
I am trying to build an Android project in the latest Android Studio (I have tried earlier versions as well) with my M2 MacBook, however, i keep getting this error message:

"can't generate a git version, this is not a git project"

I've made sure that the project is indeed a git project (.git is there and it works with windows machines). I have also tried reinstalling and recloning as well as installing xcode just to get a "magical" fix, but no luck.

UPDATE EDIT: This seems to be related to the git versioner implementation from Pascal Welsch. This error is shown because git exit value is 128 (should be 0). However, still not sure why git exit value is not 0 as it is a git project.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Thanks!